# Создание каталога в Android-приложении. Что делаю не так?

Tags: android, kotlin

В приложении необходимо реализовать функцию создания папок. Я использую следующий вариант.

```
val defaultFolderName = "/folder"
    folder = File(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(null)!!
        .absolutePath + defaultFolderName)
    folder.mkdirs()
```

Данный вариант является стандартным способом создания папок в Android.
Использовал и такой вариант.

```
val defaultFolderName = "/folder"
    folder = File(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), defaultFolderName)
    folder.mkdirs()
```

Про манифест тоже не забыл

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Папки необходимо хранить во внутренней памяти устройства. Программа выполняется без ошибок, но во внутренней памяти, я папку не нахожу. Что я могу делать не так?

Comment: Дак во внутренней памяти нужна папка или внешней? `getExternalFilesDir` это путь до внешней памяти https://stackoverflow.com/a/11351896/9271527

Comment: Мне нужна папка в памяти устройства с возможностью иметь к ней доступ из файлового менеджера